# JavaScript: How can I check for "HTMLUnknownElement"?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have made a function for to create DOM-elements:

```js
function getHtmlElement(nodeName, attrs, innerHtml) {
  var ret = null;

  if (!nodeName || typeof nodeName !== 'string') {
    throw { message: 'No nodeName-parameter assigned.' }
  }

  attrs = attrs || '';
  innerHtml = innerHtml || '';

  ret = document.createElement(nodeName);

  attrs = attrs.split(/\s/g);

  if (attrs[0]) {
    attrs.forEach(function(attr) {
      attr = attr.split(/=/);

      if (attr[1]) {
        ret.setAttribute(attr[0], attr[1]);
      }
    });
  }

  ret.innerHTML = innerHtml;  

  return ret;
}
```

The type of DOM-element is specified as the first parameter of the function.

For example: div, li, p, h1 ...

Now I would like to check if the creation of the element has worked. Because there could be a typo (diiv) or complete nonsense assigned as the parameter.

I know that there exists something called "HTMLUnknownElement" which I can inspect after the element creation. But I don't know how.

**Is HTMLUnknownElement a property of a new created DOM-element?**

**How do I check for HTMLUnknownElement?**

Comment: Something like `ret instanceof HTMLUnknownElement`.

Comment: Yep. :) That works: " var newElement = document.createElement('abc');

console.log('constructor: %s - instanceof: %s', newElement.constructor, newElement instanceof HTMLUnknownElement);
// constructor: function HTMLUnknownElement() { [native code] } - instanceof: true "

Comment: If you like: Please make your comment an answer. So that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether the created element is an instance of `HTMLUnknownElement` like this:

```
ret instanceof HTMLUnknownElement
```

Comment: or `ret instanceof window.HTMLUnknownElement` (might be needed in nodejs where window !== global)

Comment: This is not a cross-`Realm` solution.