# Why can't I access my custom component method?

Tags: javascript, web-component

Hi I have created custom web component, with a method. And after I Query for this element in DOM and then try to call this method it throws error.

```
export class Popup extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.show = this.show.bind(this);
    }

    show() {
        console.log('Works!');
    }
}

customElements.define('my-popup', Popup);
```

In the other component template I have: `<my-popup></my-popup>` and I want to do:

```
  const popup = this.querySelector('my-popup');
  popup.show();
```

this does select the element correctly, but this element does not have show method, why ?

`Uncaught TypeError: popup.show is not a function`

`console.log(popup.show)` displays *Undefined*

Full source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/vardius/webrtc-chat/blob/feature/web-components/src/client/js/components/chat/chat.js#L33) if anyone is interested in taking look at the full setup. [@WebComponent](https://github.com/vardius/web-component/blob/master/src/createTarget.js#L7) simply `define` and overrides `connectedCallback` and add template/styles nodes at the beggining of method.

Comment: Can you post a link to a demo?

Comment: It is not online, but you can check project source [Here](https://github.com/vardius/webrtc-chat/blob/feature/web-components/src/client/js/components/chat/chat.js#L33) is where I call `popup.show`

Comment: [@WebComponent](https://github.com/vardius/web-component/blob/master/src/createTarget.js#L7) simply `define ` and overrides `connectedCallback` and add template/styles nodes at the beggining of method.

Comment: It's likely that the `my-popup` element has not upgraded at the time of your query (it's still `HTMLUnknownElement`). To test this theory, you could wrap your code in an async/timeout function; or explicitly [check for it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40038859/6277151).

Comment: yep u right, doing `show` inside `window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', () => {}` fix it. Is there a nice way to wrap all components ? not repeating it all the time i want to invoke component method ?